# Knowing the end of a std::string in a loop

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std

I'm wondering how to know the end of a std::string in a loop?

for example:

```
while(string.eof()) {}
```

Remembering that it's with std::string

Thank you all.

Comment: Use `str.begin()` and `str.end()`.

Comment: Do note that `while (!eof())` in general is usually used very wrongly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop over a string like you loop over a standard library container:

```
for (auto c : s)
{
  // do something with c
}
```

or

```
for (auto it = s.begin(), end = s.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  // do something with it
}
```

where `s` is the string.

Comment: @SH.0x90 OK, don't use `c` or `it` in the loops.

Comment: you could add for with ints for paranoid people like me who thinks iterators destroy performance :D; note: pull iter.end() into variable, compiler should do it but you never know

Comment: @TheOne Ok, I did that. It does matter if you are iterating over a non-const container and the compiler cannot tell whether you modify it inside the loop.

Comment: @Creris: Last time I measured it a few years ago with the GNU C++ library, iterators performed better than array index with std::string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use iterators

```
string str="abcd";
string::iterator it=str.rbegin();//iterator pointing on d
```

if you want to do some stuff before the last character you can do like that

```
for (string::iterator it2=str.begin(); it"!=str.rbegin();++it){
   cout<<"Inside the string but not the last character\n";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: For example: While the end of a string, the last character of a string doesn't came, I will do some things inside of the loop and continue until the end of the string came, and when it came, I break the loop. - Look the example of the eof.

Answer (score 1):

> "I don't want to interact with the string,  just want a loop while the
>   end of the string doesn't came."

Really the string is a container (specific array), not file. It does not support any *state* and does not have any methods like `eof`. So you cannot do this.

If you have usual array `char buf[SZ];` what is then 'the end of the array doesn't come'?
Senseless. Array index can point to the last element, and so do string iterators shown above.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Seeing the answers above I realized that I need to use iterators in order to manipulate and to "know" the end somehow of the string. Thank you.